# Catching TextDidChange or DidEndEditing of an NSTextView instead of an NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextview

It seems that NSTextView does not have the notification DidEndEditing and TextDidChange (which both exist for an NSTextField).  Is there any similar functionality I can get out of the NSTextView?  If not is there no way to know when the user has edited the text of the NsTextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget about superclasses. An NSTextView is a kind of NSText, and every NSText can have a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/). It also, of course, posts matching [notifications](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000367-BBCFBJBH).